# jQuery index() not

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i click on a  element with a class named sections, i should get an alert showing what is it's class index, but it's showing a wrong number.

For example, if i click the first `div` element with a class named `sections`, javascript alert should say `1`, not `3`.

Is there a way to target class indexes with `click()` using jQuery?

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>this is the title</title>
<style>
.sections {
    width:200px;
    padding:30px;
    background:blue;
    margin:20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

    <div class="sections"></div>
    <div class="sections"></div>
    <div class="sections"></div>

    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script/script2.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('.sections').click(function() {
        x = $(this).index();
        alert(x);
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: class index ???

Comment: How can i get the number of which class i clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index()` with no arguments gets index within all siblings.

You have 6 siblings....3 with the class and 3 without

Try

```
var $sections =  $('.sections').click(function(){
    var x = $sections.index(this);
    alert(x);
});
```

Comment: Querying `.sections` twice is bad practice.

Comment: @BertrandMarron agree...cached it instead

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in the `selector` against which you want to index of ( if you want to get the index based on the specific class )

```
x = $('.sections').index(this);
```

```js
$('.sections').click(function() {
  x = $('.sections').index(this);
  alert(x);
});
```

```css
.sections {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 30px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>


<div class="sections"></div>
<div class="sections"></div>
<div class="sections"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct `index()`, is used to find index of an element with respect to its siblings but correct way to use it in your code is.

```
$('.sections').click(function() {
   var x = $('.sections').index(this);
   alert(x);
});
```

Also, please note that it will start from `0` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

https://api.jquery.com/index/

So, as you noticed, it's alerting it's index for itself among it's siblings in the DOM. (starting at 0)

If you want to get it's index among similar objects, you can use .index slightly differently.

```
$('.sections').click(function(){
    x = $('.sections').index($(this));
       alert(x);
});
```

This is still 0 based, so you can now expect that it will show 0 for the first item, then 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/index/):

> If we omit the argument, `.index()` will return the position of the first element within the set of matched elements in relation to its siblings:

Your first `.sections` element is in 4th position among its siblings, so it returns 3 (the first being 0).

You want to pass a selector or an element to `index()`.